# Стоит ли использовать WinForms для C++

Tags: c++, winforms, clr

Пожалуйста, ***не ставьте даунвоуты, я просто новичок!***

Я изучаю *C++*, и хочу создать свое `первое GUI-приложение`

Однако надо определиться с ***`Графической библиотекой`***

Самые популярные из них - **CLR/WinForms** и **Qt**, у меня вопрос:

> **Стоит ли использовать CLR/WinForms?**

Если да\нет, то **объясните** пожалуйста **почему**, или `порекомендуйте другую библиотеку`, только **также с объяснением**. Заранее спасибо :)

**UPD:**

И если WinForms, то **что лучше выбрать, WinAPI или WinForms?**

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139614/discussion-on-question-by-alex-u----winforms--c).